# Hide Div Based on User Selection in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm building an employee directory using AJAX/jQuery leveraging the Random User Employee Directory API. This is the actual data feed i'm using:

https://randomuser.me/api/?results=12&format=json

I have a working page which displays the users.  If someone clicks on an employee it should show the user's info--along with a few additional extra fields in a modal.

On page load--I have hidden all of these extra fields for every user---and am trying to show these extra fields in the modal (upon click).  The problem is that while a clicked user's info is populating in the modal correctly---all of the other extra info for each employee is appearing on the main page.

[Here is the jFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dt48kxvs/3/)

and my JS code:

```
//Get JSON DATA and stored data in variable Employees.
var employees;
var phone;

$.ajax({
    url: 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=12&format=json',
    success: function(data){
        employees = data.results;
        displayEmployees(employees);
        $('.extra-info').hide();
    }
});
//Create Function to Build Employee Car
function displayEmployees(employees){
    var employeesHTML = ""
    $.each(employees, function(i, employee) {
        employeesHTML += '<div class="employee">';
        employeesHTML += '<img class="employee-photo" src="' + employee.picture.large + '"></a>';
        employeesHTML += '<div class="info">';
        employeesHTML += '<div class="name">'+ employee.name.first + ' ' + employee.name.last + '</div>';
        employeesHTML += '<div class="email grey-font">'+ employee.email + '</div>';
        employeesHTML += '<div class="city grey-font">' + employee.location.city + '</div></div>';
        employeesHTML += '<div class="extra-info"><hr align="left" width="90%">';
        employeesHTML += '<div class="phone">' + employee.phone + '</div>';
        employeesHTML += '<div class="address">' + employee.location.street + ' ' + employee.location.city;
        employeesHTML += ',' + employee.location.state + ' ' + employee.location.zip + '</div>';
        employeesHTML += '<div class="birthday">Birthday: ' + employee.location.dob + '</div></div></div>';

           });

    $('.employees').html(employeesHTML);
    return phone;
};

//Create Function to Build Modal
function displayModal(employees){
    var employeesModal="";
    //create modal
    employeesModal += $(employees).html();
    $('.modal-text').html(employeesModal);
}

//Click Event To Display Modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
$('.employees').on("click", ".employee", function() {
      var current = $(this);
      var extra = current.parent().find(".extra-info");
      extra.css('display', 'block');
      modal.style.display = "block";
      displayModal(current);
});

// // When the user clicks on (x), close the modal
$('.close').on("click", function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
});

// // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

I just need to figure out how to hide all of the other user's 'extra-info' while keeping the selected users extra info displayed (in the modal).

Here is portion of the code where I am trying to only show the selected users extra info...but I'm just a bit unsure how to do this correctly:

```
//Click Event To Display Modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
$('.employees').on("click", ".employee", function() {
      var current = $(this);
      var extra = current.parent().find(".extra-info");
      extra.css('display', 'block');
      modal.style.display = "block";
      displayModal(current);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to update two functions

```
function displayModal(employees){
  var employeesModal="";
  employees.find(".extra-info").css('display', 'block');
  //create modal
  employeesModal += $(employees).html();
  $('.modal-text').html(employeesModal);
}
//Click Event To Display Modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
$('.employees').on("click", ".employee", function() {
  var current = $(this).clone();
  //var extra = current.find(".extra-info");
  //extra.css('display', 'block');
  modal.style.display = "block";
  displayModal(current);
});
```